# Is it possibe to write something like this in dev++ e.g "I Am ___ (where here i insert my age)years old" and display all this in one line

Tags: c++

I want something like this

```cpp
cout<<"I Am"; cin>>number; cout>>"years old"; <<endl;
```

but the problem is when I enter my age the "years old" appears on the next line... Whereas I want it to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't do this with `cin` but you can surely do it with `getch()` in the following way:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
char number;
cout<<"I Am ";
number= _getch(); 
while( number != ' ')
{
    cout<<number;
    number= _getch();   
}
cout <<" years old"<<endl;
}
```

While entering age on the output window, you just have to press space after typing the age, and "years old" will be printed on the same line. Don't forget to include conio.h for `_getch()`.

Comment: 100% non-portable to anything other than DOS/Windows.

Comment: I mustn't forget to include what??

Comment: conio.h library like this #include<conio.h> to use _getch() function

Comment: Can you plz type for me the whole command from the begin to avoid the errors

Comment: Because now it says ISO C++ forbibs comparison between pointer and integer[-fpermisissive]